# I’ve had sliding patio doors in which won’t open

Tags: doors, patio, sliding-glass-door

My sliding patio doors won’t open. I took off the door handle and locking lever is bent so took that out as well, the picture is what I can see now.

[image]

Comment: Can you lift the door off the track with a screwdriver/crowbar?

Comment: If the door is locked, it cannot be lifted off the track.

Comment: I had a stuck sliding glass door on some rental property where the tenant over-tightened the screw adjustable post that the locking slider slides down on. The tenant then forced the slider down and it was pinched so tight that he could not get it back up. I pushed the door closed as hard as I could and it came free.

Comment: I’ve tried literally everything don’t wanna pay for a locksmith to be told it carnt be opened thanks for the answers everyone, looks like I’ve gota buy new doors 

Comment: You removed the security board from the track? -

Answer (score 0):

There is really not enough info , you have the handle apart ok is this a problem or have the wheels worn and need to be adjusted. Sliders usually have 2 wheels that are adjusted with a screwdriver or Allen wrench. The problem I normally see is the wear on the wheel and track causes the latch to be below the catch point. On some doors I have had to replace the assembly not hard but the door has to be removed then take it to the store to match it up with a replacement. 
I know the big box stores used to carry several models if yours is worn out, but adjustment will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was presented with a case where someone over-tightened the screw adjustable post that the locking slider slides down on. He then forced the slider down and it was pinched so tight that he could not get it back up.

I pushed the door closed as hard as I could and could then move the slider up so it came free. You may be able to apply force to the door toward the lock and manipulate the slider up with a screw driver inserted through the hole left by the parts you removed. It might help to spray or squirt lubricant onto the slider.